# Pyramid in emu8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

How do I need to modify the program so that I get the following result

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
```

This is my program:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    nl db 0dh, 0ah, '$' ; nl = next line
.code
    main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov cx, 5
    mov bx, 1 
    
    for_1:    
  
    push cx             
    mov dl, 20h ; 20h is ascii code for space   
    mov ah, 02h  
            
    for_2:     
           
    loop for_2      
    mov cx, bx         
    mov dl, '1'     
    mov ah, 02h 
                                               
    for_3: 
   
    int 21h ; printing stars   
             
    loop for_3            
    lea dx, nl           
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h ; move cursor to the start of next line
    inc bx          
    pop cx          
    loop for_1 
    
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
    main endp
end main
```

I tried everything I know, and I managed other outputs, but can't accomplish this one.

Comment: Write a procedure which takes input number (1,2.3.4 or 5) and prints this many digits+nl.  Call this procedure five times with increasing input number.

Comment: Related: [Printing a triangle of characters in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65956941) prints a pyramid of the same character in every row.  Adapting it to use an ASCII character in a register should be doable.

Comment: Other near duplicates [Printing a triangle with incrementing digits instead of asterisks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72842431) (incrementing within each line), [Print triangle of numbers in assembly x86](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41743509) (working code for single digits, the Q&A is about how to adapt to multi-digit numbers.)

Answer (score 2):

Modern standalone assemblers like [EuroAssembler](https://euroassembler.eu/index.htm) allow you to write more elegant programs than emulators. I tried your assignment in command prompt of MS Windows:

```
R:\>type Zeke.asm
Zeke PROGRAM Format=COM
i     %FOR 1..5   ; Repeat the block with increasing i.
        MOV CX,%i
        CALL Line ; Call the Line procedure five times with increasing CX.
      %ENDFOR
      RET         ; Terminate program Zeke.com

Line  PROC        ; Write decimal digit CX times.
      MOV DL,CL
      ADD DL,'0'  ; Convert the binary to decimal digit.
      MOV AH,2    ; DOS function "Write character from DL".
Digit:INT 21h
      LOOP Digit  ; Repeat CX times.
      MOV DL,0Dh
      INT 21h     ; Write Carriage Return.
      MOV DL,0Ah
      INT 21h     ; Write Line Feed.
      RET
     ENDPROC Line
    ENDPROGRAM Zeke

R:\>euroasm.exe Zeke.asm
I0010 EuroAssembler version 20191104 started.
I0020 Current directory is "R:\".
I0180 Assembling source file "Zeke.asm".
I0660 16bit TINY COM file "Zeke.com" created, size=51.
I0650 Program "Zeke" assembled in 3 passes with errorlevel 0.
I0860 Listing file "Zeke.asm.lst" created, size=1597.
I0980 Memory allocation 448 KB. 142 statements assembled in 1 s.
I0990 EuroAssembler terminated with errorlevel 0.

R:\>
```

When I run the program in emulator DOSBox:

```
R:\> Zeke.com
1 
22
333
4444
55555

R:\>
```